# Import flipper to Kotlin file

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, mobile

How do I import flipper here to use `initializeFlipper` function?

```
import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication  {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost =
      object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> =
            PackageList(this).packages.apply {
              // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              // add(MyReactNativePackage())
            }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"

        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

        override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
        override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(this.applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
        initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)
  }
}
```

I tried importing flipper from `com.facebook.flipper`, but there is no positive result.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        // @react-native-community/netinfo 
        androidXCore = "1.7.0"
        // react-native-device-info
        firebaseIidVersion = "19.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}


def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add the dependency to gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.125.0' 
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.125.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.125.0'
```

Then you have to start flipper

```
fun initializeFlipper(context: Context, reactInstanceManager: ReactInstanceManager) {
    if (FlipperUtils.shouldEnableFlipper(context)) {
        val client = AndroidFlipperClient.getInstance(context)
        client.addPlugin(NetworkFlipperPlugin())
        // Add other plugins as needed, e.g., SharedPreferences, Databases
        client.start()
    }
}
```

pay close attention to the gradle so that the dependencies load well